# Server load and user activity emulation software

Tags: linux, emulation

A couple of years ago i saw a software set, whose purpose was emulating user/client activity and stress testing remote servers (mail, web, etc.). It can be installed under linux, requires a separate server to run, has a web interface and is free/open-source. I've forgotten its name and googling hasn't helped to remember it. Maybe you could advice something instead or definitely tell the name of this software.

Comment: So you ask for an - off topic and not welcome here per the rules - product recommendation?

Comment: I`m sorry for breaking the rules. But i really needed to ask the experienced people about this, because other sources couldn`t help me.

Comment: no problem. Find a freelancer, pay him for his time and advice. Google. Superuser.com possibly - not sur what the rules are there. Just NOT HERE. Seriously, and non-totally-junior web software developer should know those tools - there are tons around, I do MS only development and heck, Visual Studio has that built in. There is tons of open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these tools: 
 
- http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/
- http://gatling-tool.org/
- https://github.com/buger/gor/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is the best & Opensource and can do SMTP (MAil), HTTPS(s), SOAP, etc...

http://jmeter.apache.org/